# Why Jquery Ui does not work on safari for iphone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't understand why this code works on pc and android but not on iphone / ipad.

```
    var search_type = [<?php foreach($surveys as $sur) {
  echo "'" . $sur->id_flashpinion . "', ";
  end($surveys);
    if ($sur === key($surveys))
        echo "'" . $sur->id_flashpinion . "'";
}
?>];
for (var i = 0; i < search_type.length; i++) {
  let ids = '#volume' + search_type[i];
  var vote = $(ids).data("voted");
  if(vote != '') {
    $(ids).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: vote,
            range: "min",
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
        });
        var myVolume = vote;
        let volumeThreshold = [20, 40, 60, 80, 101]
        let volumeClasses = ["v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"]
        let classIndex = volumeThreshold.findIndex((threshold) => {return myVolume < threshold});
        changeClassTo(volumeClasses[classIndex]);

      function changeClassTo(className) {
        $(ids).removeClass();
        $(ids).addClass("volume " + className);
      }
  } else {
    $(ids).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        range: "min",
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          changeSlider(ui.value);
        },
        stop: function(_, ui){
          var id_flashpinion = ids.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
          vote = ui.value;
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '/slider/vote',
             data:{id_flashpinion:id_flashpinion, vote:vote}
        });
        $(ids).on("slide", function (event, ui) { return false; });
    }
      });


    function changeSlider(myVolume) {
      let volumeThreshold = [20, 40, 60, 80, 101]
      let volumeClasses = ["v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"]
      let classIndex = volumeThreshold.findIndex((threshold) => {return myVolume < threshold});
      changeClassTo(volumeClasses[classIndex]);
    }

    function changeClassTo(className) {
      $(ids).removeClass();
      $(ids).addClass("volume " + className);
    }
  }

}
```

the complete code is here https://codepen.io/dnl_re/pen/ZJzvJg
I also added jquery ui touch punch but it still doesn't work.

I did some tests and it seems that safari doesn't interpret the initial for well but I don't know what to change because I'm not very good at javascript

Comment: What version of jQuery, jQuery UI, Safari, and your OS?

Comment: Jquery: 3.4.1 JqueryUi: 1.12.1 JqueryUiTouch: 0.2.3 Safari: IOS 12

Comment: I found out that the script stops here on Iphone changeClassTo(volumeClasses[classIndex]); why?

Comment: Using the web inspector I discovered that the problem is let ids = '#volume' + search_type[i]; but I don't know how to solve it